# Bundle isomorphism $\Phi : TM \oplus T^*M \to T(T^*M)$.

Tags: manifolds, vector-bundles, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

> Prove that there is a bundle isomorphism $\Phi : TM \oplus T^*M \to T(T^*M)$
>    which identifies the summand $T^*M$ with the vertical
>   vectors.
>
> If $\omega_{can}$ is the canonical symplectic form on the cotangent
>   bundle $T^*M$, then prove further that one can choose $\Phi$ such that
>   the composite $d\pi \circ \Phi$ restricts to the identity on the
>   summand $TM$, where $\pi : T^*M\to M$ is the natural projection, and
>   that $\Phi^*\omega_{can}=\Omega$ where $\Omega$ is defined by 
>   $\Big((v\oplus v^*),(w\oplus w^*)\Big) \mapsto w^*(v)-v^*(w)$.

Let $(U, x^i)$ is a local coordinate on $M$ near a point $p$, and $(T^*_UM, x^i, y^i)$ is a local coordinate on $T^*M$. Then the canonical form is given by $\omega_{can}= \sum_{i=1}^n dx^i \wedge dy^i$. My idea is to define 
$$
\Phi^{-1}: \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \mapsto \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}, ~\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i} \mapsto dx^i
$$

I try to construct $\Phi$ in local coordinates and show it is independent of the choice of coordinates. But this kind of argument seems ugly and requires lots of computation. If possible, I prefer intrinsic answers, as this problem itself seems elegant and concise.

Comment: It seems you've just copied a problem from a book or some other source. I have voted to close.

Comment: I think there is something wrong. Denote $n =\dim M$. Then $T(T^*M)$ is a variety of dimension $4$, and $TM \oplus T^*M$ is of dimension $3n$ (unless it is the cartesian product, but in this case your $\Omega$ doesn't make sense).